# Instantiate new JVM per request

Tags: java, jvm, processbuilder, jvm-arguments

I have a gradle webapp and it has a submodule(resource heavy optimizer) that is just a jar(not-webapp) with a main() method.

```
Webapp/
    -> build.gradle
    -> Optimizer/
        -> src/main/Main.java
        -> SomePojo.java 
        -> build.gradle
```

Here's how I want it to work:

1. Webapp accepts a web request
2. Webapp creates an xml(optimizeme.xml) with SomePojo
3. Webapp starts a new JVM with Optimizer jar and optimizeme.xml using ProcessBuilder and subscribe to a channel X
4. Optimizer will do its job and publish to X

I need help with how to start JVM at step 3 with a submodule jar and a xml residing at a path. I can provide the path as JVM args when I start use `ProcessBuilder` but proving jar is not making much sense to me. Any suggestion?

P.S., please assume separate JVM solves the problem as I'll be planning to run those JVM on totally separate machines.

Comment: Don't you think it is better to implement the application with multithreading instead of spawning a JVM per user request?  It would be a performance degrading design if you opt to spawn JVM's per request

Comment: @EbyJacob, Optimizer is a resource heavy app that works for 20-30 mins and have multiple threads that take up most of CPU. That's the reason I want it to run as separate JVM not a thread .

Comment: So your thought-process is, I have a resource-heavy task, lets make it even more resource-heavy by spawning it as separate processes? That sounds a bit counter-intuitive.